# How can I disable search for special characters in French & Spanish in Couchbase?

Tags: go, couchbase

Example: To be searching in couch base for Gutierrez Aragon and result to be expected as Gutiérrez Aragón

"tittles": [{
"lang": "en",
"name": "Gutiérrez Aragón"
}],

Tried with stemmer_es_light but didn't worked !

Comment: please provide enough information to create a complete minimal reproduction

Answer (score 1):

You're right the main token filter (`stemmer_es_light`) to use. You could simply try using the `es` analyzer, which will essentially tokenize your text `Gutiérrez Aragón` into `["gutierrez", "aragon"]`.

Now searching for either `gutierrez`, `aragon` or `gutierrez aragon` over the field that you indexed should yield the document as a hit.

p.s. sharing your exact index definition and search request will help us assist you better.